# SQL adapter authentication in mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using the `SQL adapter` for user login in mobilefirst server.

How can i store user login credentials permanently in my hybrid app?
Once the user exit the app need to keep the login details in app.

My example code:

```
// Global variables
    var userid;   
    var useremail; 


    function loginsuccess(result) // on success function from SQL adapter      
    {
    var user  = result.invocationResult.resultSet;     
    userid = user[0].playerID;     
    useremail = user[0].email;     
    $.mobile.changePage("#gamepage"); // login to admin page    
    }
```

In this code how can i keep the user information after exit from hybrid app.(Once the user login don't ask the user to login again).

Answer (score 0):

> How can i store user login credentials permanently in my hybrid app?

If you want to persist the user information in the device, you need to implement that; there is nothing built-in to accomplish that.

You have several options:

1) HTML5 localStorage (a W3C standard, google it), but it has issues:

- If the user will decide to clear the application cache, this will be gone
- It will store the user information in clear text, not very secure
- Limited to 5MB or so

2) IBM MobileFirst Platform's Encrypted Offline Cache, basically localStorage but provides encryption. But it too has some issues:

- Deprecated (will be removed in future releases)
- If the user will decide to clear the application cache, this will be gone
- Limited to 5MB or so

3) IBM MobileFirst Platform's JSONStore - what you should probably pick:

- No storage limit
- Provides encryption
- Multi-user support
- Will be gone only if deleting the application

  - [Read more about JSONStore in the user documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html)
  - [JSONStore tutorials](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/working-offline/jsonstore/)

---

It also sounds like you want to implement "Remember Me" functionality.
Note that such functionality reduces the application security...

Related questions for that:

- [How to maintain session in IBM worklight server side login module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270223/how-to-maintain-session-in-ibm-worklight-server-side-login-module/)
- [How to implement password protect security in JsonStore Worklight 6.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684029/how-to-implement-password-protect-security-in-jsonstore-worklight-6-2#comment40148500_25685034) ([see Simple Data Sharing documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_simple_data_sharing.html))